# Amazon API Gateway - Intentional attacks for costs raising

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS and would like to deploy a microservice on Amazon Web Services. The function code shall be in AWS Lambda and this functions shall be triggered through AWS API Gateway.

My lambda functions itself are protected via authorization. Furthermore, the number of authorised requests are within the free tier.

**Now my questions:**

- Can unauthorised attacks to Amazon API Gateway let the costs explode?
- Can i prevent my Amazon API Gateway from such attacks?
- Can i set a costs limit and shut the API off, in case of too high bills?
- Are intentionally API attacks common?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can unauthorized attacks to Amazon API Gateway let the costs explode?

Yes. This can happen.

> Can I prevent my Amazon API Gateway from such attacks?

You can use a web application firewall to reduce these malicious attacks using AWS WAF.

- Setup AWS CloudFront integrated with AWS WAF in front of API Gateway.
- Enabling API Keys in API Gateway so that direct access to API Gateway without the API Key is not possible. You can create use an API Key in Origin Headers in CloudFront so that for requests forwarded to API Gateway uses this API Key in headers.

> Can I set a costs limit and shut the API off, in case of too high
>   bills?

You can enable throttling so that very high peaks of traffic will be throttled for API Gateway reducing Cost Peaks (The negative side of this is that it affects the quality of service for real users). However, if you need to implement shutting down the API based on request rate, it's not directly supported with API Gateway. You need to do a custom implementation for this.

> Are intentionally API attacks common?

I haven't seen much attacks for the APIs I deployed so far. Having said that it can be very subjective based on the nature of your business & etc.  However, I have seen Bot based invocations more often. When you are using AWS WAF you can implement a Honey Pot easily to prevent these. Example code is available in AWS Labs in [Github for Bad Bot Blocking](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-sample) to connect with WAF.

Comment: Please correct your answer with the information I provided in my answer

Answer (score 4):

> Can unauthorized attacks to Amazon API Gateway let the costs explode?

If you enable any type of authorization at the API Gateway layer (IAM, Custom, Cognito), API Gateway will **NOT** charge you for unauthorized requests. However, Lambda functions backing Custom Authorizers are still billed as normal Lambda invocations.

The same applies to throttled requests, if you have rate rate limiting enabled on your API.

Comment: I think this response is a bit misleading; as far as I can see from the documentation, you will still be charged for the custom authoriser lambda invocations, even if they are denying access.

Comment: You mean the Lambda cost itself? I guess I meant that API Gateway will not charge you. I can clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave a comment here as this is one of the top results when you search for this topic and this has an official source from AWS. I spoke to AWS Support and they confirmed that you *do not* pay for unauthed requests at the APIGW level, however you do pay for the authorizer lambda running the verification code:
[image]

To clarify:

1. Request comes in to API Gateway
2. Request is forwarded to Lambda custom authorizer
3. Request fails custom authorizer <-- You are charged for this lambda invocation
4. API Gateway rejects this request <-- You *are not* charged for this at the APIGW level

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answers, there is a way to avoid paying for any requests, even with lambda authorization: You can set a custom header or query string as [Identity source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html#http-api-lambda-authorizer.identity-sources).

If the caller does not send the specified header/query key, the authorizor lambda will not be executed and no costs will occur.
Just make sure that the header/query key is not a common one, i.e. `Authorizaion` or `apiKey`.